# Grok pattern - sometimes nesting bracket

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a difficult log for me.

Because sometimes I have nested bracket and sometimes i don't.

How to parse it in a grok.

```
[2022-09-05 17:27:24,537] [apps-thread | test-policy] WARN
[2022-09-06 14:19:25,708] [App (app-1) thread #1 - AppsConsumer[apps-notify]] INFO


 grok {
         match => [ "message", "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[HOW TO HANDLE THIS:thread\] %{LOGLEVEL:log_level}" ]
         tag_on_failure => ["failed-to-parse"]
    }
```

Please help

Comment: what's the issue? With this pattern: `\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{DATA:data}\] %{LOGLEVEL:log_level}` I get `apps-thread·|·test-policy ` and `App·(app-1)·thread·#1·-·AppsConsumer[apps-notify] ` from the lines you gave.

Comment: @baudsp thanks, now i know there i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was convinced that the above proposal would give me:

```
{
   "log_level": "] INFO",
   "someField": "App (app-1) thread # 1 - AppsConsumer [apps-notify",
   "timestamp": "2022-09-06 14:19: 25,708"
}
```

because the grok will stop on the first squere bracket "]"

Today in the morning I understand that there is a squere bracket space log_level, which is why it does not stop on the first bracket